# inDesign: how to import several images from the same Photoshop document while conserving their relative size?

Tags: adobe-indesign

After slicing my Photoshop document into parts with images and text, I want to import these parts (as images) into my inDesign document. But I want the font used in these parts to conserve the same size across all of the parts. In other words, I want to keep the same size relative to each other just as in original Photoshop document.

How to do that?

Comment: I am not sure, if I understood your question, but setting the image sizes to 100% should do it. (Select the images you imported, switch to the white arrow and set the scaling settings to 100%)

Comment: If you place the images by clicking once, rather than dragging out a destination frame, you will find the images are imported at their native size. To resize them, select all and enter a percentage in the control bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if your Photoshop file resolution is 72 pixels per inch and if you set up InDesign document intent to Web, then the two documents resolutions should be the same.

[image]

Then if you place your image slices using FILE > PLACE, they should all be at 100% of their original size.

Comment: ...and don't click-and-drag, as jongware points out.